# need help connecting to mysql database

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, database

0

hi need to connect to a mysql server i have set up on godaddy.com

my code is

```
var dbcon : IDbConnection; //port is 3303 
var connectionString : String = "Server=xxxxx.xx.xx.x; Uid=lxxxx; Pwd=xxxx; Database=lxxx;";

dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
dbcon.Open();
```

however my connection is rejected, i suspect i need to put in a port number.can anyone tell me how would i specify a port number in my connection string?? thx

Comment: MySQL default port is 3306 not 3303..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLConnection class is used to connect to SQL Server. To connect to MySQL, you have to use the [MySQL .NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).  When using the MySQL Connector, you should be using the class MySQLConnection.  The [connection string options reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) should be able to help you get all the options correct.  When using the MySQL connector, you don't need to specify the port unless you are using something other than the default, which is 3306.

Comment: dayum , thanks a lot bro, took me forever to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

usually port number are specified as part of server name. e.g. `'localhost:8808'`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Server = <assigned-dns-name-or-ip>:3303, Uid=<youruserid>, Pwd=<yourpassword>, Database=<databasename>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String = "Server=xxxxx.xx.xx.x; Uid=lxxxx; Pwd=xxxx; Database=lxxx; Port=3303;";
```

Found here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql